# node.js socket.io & memcached - using PHP Session ID as Socket.IO Nickname

Tags: php, node.js, session, socket.io, memcached

I understand if this is a silly questions.

I have a site that is delivered by PHP and every user has a userid stored in a memcached SESSION.

I'm also using node.js to deliver socket.io and using a nickname to know who the user is. (eg: it passes the userid over when the connection is initially made).

Is there anyway to get node.js to connect to the PHP SESSION to get the user ID from there when the connection is made - this would avoid people being able to fake being people. (more secure).

Or are there better ways to go about this?
I would use SSL/HTTPS/WS but the site is HTTP and I believe mixing the 2 isn't allowed in some browsers now.

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check this npm out to get php sessions in node : https://npmjs.org/package/nodePhpSessions